# How to select everything from all_objects using different schemas at once - PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle12c

Let's say that I have few schemas A, B, C, D (in reality they are like 10+).
I'm trying to search for a specific data type in all of my schemas and I'm using the system table ALL_OBJECTS. The thing which I hope I can sidestep is executing the same query:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME LIKE '%something%';
```

manually through all schemas.

Is there an easy way to execute the script above for all of the schemas at once?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The different schemas will just have a different owner. What would you need to execute it multiple times?

Comment: My goal is to see whether I use a certain datatype through all of my schemas, more specifically in the procedures and functions for each user.

Comment: You mean the data types of the arguments and return types?

Comment: well, let's say I use 'FILE_DATASTORE' in some of my packages from some of my schemas.
For example, let's say that it occurs in the my_package package in schema A. 
I want to go through all of my schemas and validate in which schemas does the given datatype occur. Since I have many schemas, the process of going through each one separately makes the whole search quite slow and prone to human errors. 
p.s. I will try to use your answer for now

Comment: if it's in the input arguments, the query below will show it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one:

```
SELECT PROC.OWNER          AS SCHEMA_NAME,
       PROC.OBJECT_NAME    AS PROCEDURE_NAME,
       ARGS.ARGUMENT_NAME,
       ARGS.IN_OUT,
       ARGS.DATA_TYPE,
       ARGS.DATA_LENGTH,
       ARGS.DATA_PRECISION,
       ARGS.DATA_SCALE,
       ARGS.DEFAULTED,
       ARGS.DEFAULT_VALUE
  FROM SYS.ALL_PROCEDURES PROC
       LEFT JOIN SYS.ALL_ARGUMENTS ARGS ON PROC.OBJECT_ID = ARGS.OBJECT_ID
 WHERE PROC.OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
   AND PROC.OBJECT_NAME LIKE '%something%'
 ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME, PROCEDURE_NAME, ARGS.POSITION;
```

This will give you all procedures in all schemas and list them by argument list with types.